# Symfony flush and relation : Column cannot be NULL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two simple entities : **Cabinet** and **Personne** with "OneToOne" relation. But when I add Cabinet, I have this error : **Column 'personne_id' cannot be null**.

**Cabinet entity :**

```
class Cabinet
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LogicielBundle\Entity\Personne", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $personne;

public function setPersonne(\LogicielBundle\Entity\Personne $personne)
{
    $this->personne = $personne;

    return $this;
}

public function getPersonne()
{
    return $this->personne;
}
```

**Personne entity :**

```
class Personne {

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UtilisateurBundle\Entity\Cabinet", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $cabinet;

public function setCabinet(\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\Cabinet $cabinet)
{
    $this->cabinet = $cabinet;

    return $this;
}

public function getCabinet()
{
    return $this->cabinet;
}
```

**My Controller is very simple :**

```
    public function ajouterAction(Request $request)
{
    $personne = new Personne();
    $cabinet = new Cabinet();

    $cabinet->setPersonne($personne);
    $personne->setCabinet($cabinet);

    $form = $this->createForm('utilisateur_cabinet_form', $cabinet);
    $this->submit($form);
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        dump($personne);
        dump($cabinet);
        $em->persist($cabinet);
        $em->flush();
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Le cabinet « '.$cabinet->getVersions()[0]->getLibelle().' » a été ajouté.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('utilisateur_cabinet_index'));
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'title' => 'Ajouter un nouveau cabinet'
    );
}
```

dump($cabinet) ans dump($personne) is true ; can you help me ?

Comment: You should display ID mapping information of your entities to see what's going on. Your `JoinColumn` definition seems incomplete, missing *name* and *referencedColumnName*. Also, if it's a bidirectional relationship you should indicate who is the owning and who is the inverse side by using inversedBy and mappedBy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to allow the Setter parameter to be null as well (nullable=true isn't enough here):

```
 public function setPersonne(\LogicielBundle\Entity\Personne $personne = null)
```

Comment: Thank @LBA, it's work true. But why and nullable if I don't want null data ? Thank you :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I probably misunderstood you - so the column must not be null in fact for both sides of the association?

Comment: Make sure to set your owning and reverse side of the association: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: Thanks but If I don't want bidirectionnal relation ? But your first reply is work true ...

Comment: You'll get a bidirectional relation anyway, but for a one-to-one: The owning side of a OneToOne association is the entity with the table containing the foreign key. You need to define it in your annotation.